# What is supported MQ version on V1R13

Tags: ibm-mq

I am new to SOF and am beginner for MQ on zO/S.

We are currently running  V700  MQ. and the Z/OS version is V1R12. We will subsequently upgrade to Z/OS V1R13 and later to Z/OS V2R2.

So what version of MQ will the above Z/OS versions support?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip your question. It isn't what versions of IBM MQ does z/OS support, it's which versions of z/OS are supported by which versions of IBM MQ.

The system requirements for IBM MQ are listed here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006467

If you look into the 'z/OS' section of each you'll find which versions they support.

Looks like the latest version of IBM MQ which supports 1.12 is MQ 7.1, which doesn't support 2.2.

IBM MQ 8 supports 1.13 and 2.2 though. A possible migration path is:

1) Upgrade to z/OS 1.13

2) Upgrade to IBM MQ 8

3) Upgrade to z/OS 2.2 at a later date